# WOL on Gigabyte MA785GT-UD3H for Logmein?

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan, wake-up, logmein

I have a Gigabyte MA785GT-UD3H mainboard. I want to wake my computer up using Logmein, however, I could not found any WOL option on BIOS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need a Realtek 8111C [driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Answer (score 1):

Product [specifications at Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=142) state that the 8111c supports WOL.

This [extensive Thread](http://community.logmein.com/t5/Free/Wake-on-LAN/td-p/31061) at Logmein details what steps you need to follow to enable WOL via Logmein.  From the main post that details this...

> Please confirm that the host is in a supported sleep mode (stand-by, sleep, or hibernation mode: ACPI specification S3 or S4).  For a Windows PC that is powered off (but still plugged in), confirm that Wake on LAN is enabled in the computer's BIOS.
>
> Tip: Consult the user guide of your computer or motherboard to locate the appropriate BIOS switch, (usually Wake on LAN from S5).
>
> Please also confirm that at least one other LogMeIn host on the same LAN is online and available.

Now... your [motherboard manual](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-ma785gt-ud3h_v1.1_e.pdf) indicates on page 53, that if EuP is **ENABLED** that wake on LAN becomes unavailable.  Since there appears to be no direct control to enable and disable it, if you have the proper ACPI power state enabled, WOL should work as long as you leave EuP disabled.

As the thread at Logmein support get to detailing... you need to make sure you have port 9 forwarded to that computer's internal IP address in your router.  In fact, just read that thread as a good once-over.